# Efficient method to join the columns using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

PROBLEM:
I need to merge the columns by identifying the headernames and they work as desired by using the below code.

The code is very inefficient as I am using an eval to accomplish the job and I believe it makes unnecessay multiple passes which is not recommended. Is there a way I can optimize my code to merge the columns?
My code works good only for one item fruits since "CriteriaMatchArray"  for many items I need to pass the result again as input and run it making inefficient.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18FSwIDZ5H5nqrbwq-VIMoHouW6f0cSZ7sTIgN9RxBc0/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2d6d.png

Hence the end result is nothing but 2d array as shown in the image

I have code below

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<script>
    var table = [
        ["Sl.no","fruits 1", "fruits 2", "fruits 3", "fruits 4", "fruits 5", "vegetables 1", "vegetables 2"],
        ["1","banana", "apple", "orange", "", "", "carrot", "cabbage"],
        ["2","watermelon", "apple", "orange", "", "", "beans", ""]
    ]

    //document.write(JSON.stringify(table))

    var str = [],
        m = [];
    var firstJoiningPosition = -1;
    CriteriaMatchArray = ["fruits"] //this is the input (currently processes only 1 item in list) and user can change or add more

    for (var i = 0; i < table[0].length; i++) {
        if (table[0][i].indexOf(CriteriaMatchArray[0]) == -1) {
            str.push("table[i][" + i + "]")
        } else {
            if (firstJoiningPosition == -1)
                firstJoiningPosition = i
            m.push("table[i][" + i + "]")
        }
    }

    str[firstJoiningPosition] = m.join("+ '#' +")
    evalstring = str.join(",")

    document.write('<pre>Given table   ' + JSON.stringify(table, null, 4) + '</pre>')

    var result = []

    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        eval("result.push(" + "[" + evalstring + "]" + ")")
    }

    document.write('<pre>Result after joining   ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>')
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 95% of what you want. Now you just have to create the headings according to whether isFruits or isVegs:

```js
  const getInd = (headings, type) => headings.reduce((accum, item, ind) => {
    if (item.indexOf(type) != -1) {
      accum.push(ind)
    }
    return accum;
  }, [])
  
const convert = (table, arrCriteria) => {
  const isFruits = arrCriteria.indexOf('fruits') != -1
  const isVegs = arrCriteria.indexOf('vegetables') != -1
  const headings = table[0];
  const arrFruitsInd = getInd(headings, 'fruits');
  const arrVegsInd = getInd(headings, 'vegetables')
  const extract = (arr, arrInd) => arr.filter((item, ind) => arrInd.indexOf(ind) != -1)
  const results = table.slice(1).map(arr => {
    const arrFruitsExtract = extract(arr, arrFruitsInd)
    const arrFruits = isFruits ? [arrFruitsExtract.filter(item => item).join('#')] : arrFruitsExtract
    const arrVegsExtract = extract(arr, arrVegsInd)
    const arrVegs = isVegs ? [arrVegsExtract.filter(item => item).join(', ')] : arrVegsExtract
    return [arr[0]].concat(arrFruits.concat(arrVegs))
  })
 return results
}

const table = [
        ["Sl.no","fruits 1", "fruits 2", "fruits 3", "fruits 4", "fruits 5", "vegetables 1", "vegetables 2"],
        ["1","banana", "apple", "orange", "", "", "carrot", "cabbage"],
        ["2","watermelon", "apple", "orange", "", "", "beans", ""]
    ]

// console.log(convert(table, ['fruits']))
console.log(convert(table, ['vegetables', 'fruits']))
// console.log(convert(table, ['vegetables']))
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, But I am looking for a more dynamic solution. the indexOf fruits, vegetables cannot be coded and they are to be taken based on input CriteriaMatchArray. What I see from your solution is that, its hardcoded. Is there a way I can make it dynamic. I am really thankful to you.

Comment: The data is just a sample, the real table consist of company attributes like organization postal code, organization street, Organization phone, likewise the number of categories (fruits and vegetables) are infinitely large so this solution cannot be hardcoded and we need to make it dynamically determine the category

Comment: I am getting the empty result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBRAP.png

Comment: Provide another example instance so I can see what you mean with regard to index of vegetables/fruits etc

Comment: I mean const arrFruitsInd = getInd(headings, 'fruits');
  const arrVegsInd = getInd(headings, 'vegetables') should be removed as they need to be dynamically generated from the CriteriaMatchArray

Comment: oh so you mean these headings are dynamic, and you want the user to get the merged heading names. So it could be "shoes 1" shoes 2" and so on.

Comment: Yes exactly, it can be anything

Answer (score 0):

I would first define the ranges of the column indices that need to be grouped together. So if the criterion is "fruits", then

- Column index 0 maps to a column (no change to "Sl.no")
- Column indices 1 - 5 map to a column (grouping "fruits")
- Column index 6 maps to a column (no change to vegetables)
- Column index 7 maps to a column (no change to vegetables)

So the ranges -- in JavaScript notation -- would be:

```
[
    [0, 1],
    [1, 6],
    [6, 7],
    [7, 8]
]
```

Note that the second index is the one *after* the last column to include, much like the `slice` method works.

Once you have identified that, it is easy to iterate the rows of the original table, and to group cells together based on that information.

Here is an implementation:

```js
function collapse(table, criteria) {
    let head = table[0];
    let slices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < head.length; i++) {
        let match = criteria.find(group => head[i].startsWith(group));
        let start = i;
        while (head[i+1]?.startsWith(match)) i++;
        slices.push([start, i+1]);
    }
    return table.map((row, i) =>
        slices.reduce((acc, [j, k]) => 
            acc.concat(i 
                ? row.slice(j, k).filter(Boolean).join(", ")
                : k > j+1 ? "Combined " + row[j].split(" ")[0] : row[j]
            )
        , [])
    );
}

let table = [
    ["Sl.no","fruits 1", "fruits 2", "fruits 3", "fruits 4", "fruits 5", "vegetables 1", "vegetables 2"],
    ["1","banana", "apple", "orange", "", "", "carrot", "cabbage"],
    ["2","watermelon", "apple", "orange", "", "", "beans", ""]
]

// Demo run:
let result = collapse(table, ["fruits"]);
console.log(result);
```