# Splitting an array into equal chunks and then allot remaining

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array where I need to divide equally into **person number of chunks**.

1. if there are 100 items in array for 10 persons, 10 chunks to be created with each 10 items
2. if there are 100 items in array for 9 persons, 9 chunks to be created and each would get 9 items and the **extra should be given to first person, second person and so on.** which means Person 1 = 10; Person 2, 3, 4 ... would have 9 items
3. if there are 100 items in array for 11 persons, 11 chunks are to be created with each would get 10 and the extra should be given to first person. which means

> ```
> Person 1 is 10
> Person 2 is 9
> Person 3 is 9
> Person 4 is 9
> Person 5 is 9
> Person 6 is 9
> Person 7 is 9
> Person 8 is 9
> Person 9 is 9
> Person 10 is 9
> Person 11 is 9
> ```

I have tried with

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'chunk', {
    value: function(chunkSize) {
        var array = this;
        return [].concat.apply([],
            array.map(function(elem, i) {
                return i % chunkSize ? [] : [array.slice(i, i + chunkSize)];
            })
        );
    }
});

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ..., 150, 151].chunk(Math.floor(151 / 31))
```

but that would gives me an incorrect allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the remainder of the division to get the number of slices that need an extra element. Then use the index in the new (chunked) array to determine whether it needs that extra element (i.e. when that index is less than the remainder).

NB: I would not alter the Array prototype. Just make this a plain function.

Implementation:

```js
function partition(arr, length) {
    let rest = arr.length % length;
    let size = Math.floor(arr.length / length);
    let j = 0;
    return Array.from({length}, (_, i) => arr.slice(j, j += size + (i < rest)));
}

let data = Array.from({length: 151}, (_,i) => i+1);
let result = partition(data, 31);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a perfect solution I really appreciate it

Comment: Could you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903252/efficient-method-to-join-the-columns-using-arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to split an array in chunk:

```js
function* chunks(arr, n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += n) {
    yield arr.slice(i, i + n);
  }
}

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ..., 150, 151];
console.log([...chunks(a, Math.floor(151 / 31))]);
```

Then you can adapt this code to move the last element in first place (if you want first person to be the most empty).

As a side note, you can replace this:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ..., 150, 151];
```

with this:

```
let a = [...Array(151).keys()];
```

Comment: Its still incorrect - https://jsfiddle.net/L7zh24de/1/ the last member gets 1 item, the objective is to get all of the same amount of items and if extra are remaining allot them to the starting person onwards. Could you please help by revising your code?

Comment: If 31 persons are specified then only 31 chunks need to be created, but this solution creates more than person number of chunks

Comment: I have edited my question for better clarity